# Programatically created edit text is also getting focus while tapping another edit text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have created multiple edit texts programmatically using existing edit text available in XML file but when the main edit text gets the focus then the edit texts created dynamically also getting focus. My code is as below :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_worker_reg);
        existingContact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.workerPhone);
        drawable = existingContact.getBackground();
    }

 public void addAnotherContactNumber(View view) {
        final CharSequence[] options = { "Work", "Home","Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(WorkerRegActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Contact Number!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Work"))
                {
                    linearLayout =     (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
                    EditText newContact = new EditText(WorkerRegActivity.this);
                    newContact.setHint("Phone NO." + (newContactIndex - 1));
                        newContact.setHintTextColor(existingContact.getHintTextColors());
                    newContact.setInputType(existingContact.getInputType());
                    newContact.setLayoutParams(existingContact.getLayoutParams());

                    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        newContact.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                    } else {
                        newContact.setBackground(drawable);
                    }

                    linearLayout.addView(newContact, newContactIndex);
                    newContactIndex += 1;

                    contactList.add(newContact);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Home"))
                {

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

Actually I want to create multiple edit texts using an existing edit text as defined in XML file with same background but when one edit text gains focus another one also gains the focus automatically. Please help.....

Answer (score 1):

When you add new editTexts, just add a property line switching off the focus :

```
edittext.clearFocus();
```

where edittext is the id of your edittext.

If this doesn'twork, you can use this :

```
<!-- Dummy item to prevent AutoCompleteTextView from receiving focus -->

<LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"/>

<!-- :nextFocusUp and :nextFocusLeft have been set to the id of this component
     to prevent the dummy from receiving focus again -->
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autotext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/autotext" android:nextFocusLeft="@id/autotext"/>
```

This is just  aworkaround to trick android to give focus to something else than the edit text. Remember, however, that you have to put the dummy element just before the editText you wish to revoke focus from.

Answer (score 0):

While doing such thing we should use different object of drawable rather than same instance.

```
Drawable clone = drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable();
```